# Google Chome how to fetch for malware?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, malware

In the last 2 weeks, I have noticed an annoying malware haunting me on Google Chrome. Most often when I do a simple google search (obviously on google.com), after a few seconds the tab gets cloned into a fake google search **Example** searching for "how to read chrome network log" opened this fake website https://d.abcweathercast.xyz/api/mktgl/search?p=how+to+read+chrome+network+log&subid=fo59g which then redirected me to this: https://m.nearbyme.io/search/?search_term=how%20to%20read%20chrome%20network%20log&brand=gc1. So I have I head to `chrome://net-export/` to try and diagnose the problem, recorded for some seconds and I got 6 occurences of both websites in the same log file. I'm pretty sure this malware is infecting chrome because firefox and edge never redirect me to such websites. How do I diagnose the problem? Tried disabling all my extensions but I still run in the same problem. What other thing can be causing this issue ?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a factory reset of chrome?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply didn't see your comment. How can I do so? Also will I be able to backup my data first ? (Browsing history, Downloads, Extensions, etc)